# drupal: Allow anonymous access to views (via Services Views)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have created a View that can be accessed using the Services Views module. The URL looks like this http:///api/views/

However, when I try to access the endpoint via CURL, I would get the login page of Drupal.

Is it possible to configure a specific Services endpoint so that it is publicly accessible?

By the way, I'm new to Drupal so I'm trying to find if there's an easy way to configure this.

Comment: I've never used this module, but maybe it's a permissions problem. Could you check the permissions of this module?

Comment: I have checked the permission for anonymous user, but still same behavior

Comment: And the views permission? Maybe the Service View uses a View that shows content allowed only for logged users.